# Using For /F to create new folders in all sub directories

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a standardised directory structure to prepare a drive ready for tidying and migration to a new location. What I'm looking to do is run a batch file in the root of the drive which works through all subdirectories and creates a new folder called 'Archive' in each of them ready for files to be tidied up and later moved or deleted.

I'm trying to use FOR /F with an MD command to make the folders, but I'm really struggling to understand the syntax re. tokens and variables. I'm trying to adapt from something like

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do @copy "%a" "c:\Single-Folder"
```

which I nabbed from over [here](https://superuser.com/questions/137336/copy-all-files-in-subfolders-to-single-folder-on-xp) replacing @copy with @md... but I'm really out of my depth.

Any offers of help much appreciated

Comment: try XCOPY with parameter /S or /E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are using:

```
dir /b /s /a-d
```

lists everything except directories (the - sign negates the attribute). So the right command you have to use is this:

```
dir /b /s /ad
```

(try it yourself!).

`FOR /F` reads the output of the `dir` command, one line of text at a time. `tokens=*` will get the whole line (removing leading spaces). I think you need this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /s /ad') do @echo mkdir "%a\Archive"
```

when you are sure it is right, remove the `echo` command to actually execute the `mkdir`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is this type of structure:

```
@Echo OFF

REM By Elektro H@cker

For /D /R "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\" %%#  in (*) do (MKDIR "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Single-Folder\%%~p#")

Pause&Exit
```